# Error: port uninstall failed: too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)

Tags: mac-osx

I'm trying to uninstall MacPorts, following the instructions at [MacPorts Manual](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html).

But there is a cyclical dependency, related to python26, X and tk.
The is my port list:

```
bzip2                          @1.0.6          archivers/bzip2
db46                           @4.6.21         databases/db46
expat                          @2.0.1          textproc/expat
fontconfig                     @2.8.0          graphics/fontconfig
freetype                       @2.4.8          print/freetype
freetype                       @2.4.8          print/freetype
gdbm                           @1.10           databases/gdbm
gdbm                           @1.10           databases/gdbm
gettext                        @0.18.1.1       devel/gettext
libiconv                       @1.14           textproc/libiconv
libxml2                        @2.7.8          textproc/libxml2
ncurses                        @5.9            devel/ncurses
ncurses                        @5.9            devel/ncurses
ncursesw                       @5.8            devel/ncursesw
openssl                        @1.0.0g         devel/openssl
python26                       @2.6.7          lang/python26
readline                       @6.2.000        devel/readline
sqlite3                        @3.7.10         databases/sqlite3
tcl                            @8.5.11         lang/tcl
tk                             @8.5.11         x11/tk
Xft2                           @2.2.0          x11/Xft2
xorg-kbproto                   @1.0.5          x11/xorg-kbproto
xorg-libpthread-stubs          @0.3            x11/xorg-libpthread-stubs
xorg-libX11                    @1.4.4          x11/xorg-libX11
xorg-libXau                    @1.0.6          x11/xorg-libXau
xorg-libxcb                    @1.7            x11/xorg-libxcb
xorg-libXdmcp                  @1.1.0          x11/xorg-libXdmcp
xorg-libXext                   @1.3.0          x11/xorg-libXext
xorg-libXScrnSaver             @1.2.1          x11/xorg-libXScrnSaver
xorg-renderproto               @0.11.1         x11/xorg-renderproto
xorg-scrnsaverproto            @1.2.1          x11/xorg-scrnsaverproto
xorg-xcb-proto                 @1.6            x11/xorg-xcb-proto
xorg-xextproto                 @7.2.0          x11/xorg-xextproto
xorg-xproto                    @7.0.22         x11/xorg-xproto
xrender                        @0.9.6          x11/xrender
zlib                           @1.2.5          archivers/zlib
```

How can I get rid of MacPorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the `--follow-dependents` option and just use:

```
sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

Then proceed with the second step.

Even if the first step fails, the following `rm` should delete all the files installed by MacPorts. It usually installs all files into `/opt/local`, except for a few files that have to be in a specific directory, such as the startup files in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and the application bundles in `/Applications/MacPorts`.

Comment: Thanks. As I had homebrew also installed I was afraid to delete more stuff than necessary. But it happened homebrew was using another base location (/usr/local).